# Xcode build fails because LS3Renderer.framework is missing. What/where is LS3Renderer.framework?

Tags: ios, xcode7, google-cast

Following instructions here: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/ios_sender#setup, I am trying to add GoogleCast to a iPad app. When I attempt to build the app it fails with the error message: "/Library/Frameworks/LS3Renderer.framework is missing from working copy."

I understand that this means the named framework is not where it is supposed to be. The thing is, I have searched my system for the framework and don't find it, ***and*** I have searched the web for information on the framework and have turned up nothing.

Does anyone know what LS3Renderer.framework is and where I might get a copy, or have any insight into the error I'm getting from Xcode?

Comment: Have you made sure all the framework libraries that are mentioned in the https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/ios_sender are linked?

Comment: Yes, indeed. That's why I am baffled.